# Is there a way to customize the minimum value of the RangeSlider widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, rangeslider

I just dont know what to do. Is there a way to customize the minimum value of the RangeSlider widget in flutter??

I want the Rangeslider minimum value to be 400 or something. can you help me guys??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in that case, you can do a small hack..like..say you have a slider from 0 to 100 but you want a slider from 400 to 500..so, now you can get the value from slider..and then, if you get some 'x' value, say some 25..then your required value will be 'x+400', in our case 425..hope it answers.

Comment: Thankyou. Now I have the idea. Thankyou very much.